# Response Redirect is not working with Primary Id

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I use response redirect if I want to use my Primary ID, which is a auto increment value?

I am trying to link it to another page, but there is error with the codes I used.

```
Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx?ordersId=" +ordersId);
```

Comment: int ordersId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ordersId"].ToString());

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format @artm

Comment: `int.Parse("32") = 32`, `int.Parse("32a") = format exception`. Check what your query string is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried investigating your confirmation.aspx?

```
int orderId = 0;
string qryString = Request.QueryString["ordersId"];
if (int.TryParse(qryString, out orderId)) {
    // order id ok
}
else {
    Response.Write("Invalid order id:" + qryString);
}
```